# Django 2.0 - Reverse for 'password_change_done' not found. 'password_change_done' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-templates

I'm having this error message after trying to change my app's password.

Do you have any idea of what's causing this route to fail?

Actually, it is changing the password but it isn't rendering the success template "password_change_done.html".

Thanks!

**app/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path
​
from . import views
​
app_name = 'account'
​
urlpatterns = [
    # path('login/', views.user_login, name='login'),
    path('', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
​
    # login / logout urls
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='registration/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('logout-then-login/', auth_views.logout_then_login, name='logout_then_login'),
​
    # change password urls
    path('password-change/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(), name='password_change'),
    path('password_change/done/', auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(), name='password_change_done'),
]
​

​
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
# NoReverseMatch at /account/password-change/
# Reverse for 'password_change_done' not found. 'password_change_done' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
# Request Method:   POST
# Request URL:  http://localhost:8000/account/password-change/
# Django Version:   2.0.4
# Exception Type:   NoReverseMatch
# Exception Value:  
# Reverse for 'password_change_done' not found. 'password_change_done' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
# Exception Location:   C:\env\django_social_website\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 632
# Python Executable:    C:\env\django_social_website\Scripts\python.exe
# Python Version:   3.6.3
# Python Path:  
# ['C:\\Projects\\django_social_website',
#  'C:\\env\\django_social_website\\Scripts\\python36.zip',
#  'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\DLLs',
#  'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib',
#  'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3',
#  'C:\\env\\django_social_website',
#  'C:\\env\\django_social_website\\lib\\site-packages',
#  'C:\\env\\django_social_website\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-28.8.0-py3.6.egg',
#  'C:\\env\\django_social_website\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg']
# Server time:  Thu, 5 Apr 2018 21:34:22 +0000

​
```

**app/templates/registration/password_change_form.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
​
{% block title %}Change your password{% endblock %}
​
{% block content %}
    <h1>Change your password</h1>
    <p>Use the form below to change your password.</p>
    <form action="." method="post">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p><input type="submit" value="Change"></p>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
​

​
```

**app/templates/registration/password_change_done.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
​
{% block title %}Password changed{% endblock %}
​
{% block content %}
    <h1>Password changed</h1>
    <p>Your password has been successfully changed.</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: do you use redirect after successful password change? can you show the code? Maybe the error is that is has to be 'account:password_change_done' but without the code it is only a guess .

Comment: Hi Tobit, actually that's the code.

In the "urls.py" file I´m using the "PasswordChangeView" view, which after looking into django's default views has a success_url variable that defaults to reverse_lazy('password_change_done'). Perhaps the namespace that I created is causing all the trouble.

Here you have the function  and a link to Django's default auth views:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py

Look for the class PasswordChangeView in it.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the problem here is, as Tobit hints, is that your URLs are using an application namespace called `account`. That has been defined by the presence of `app_name = 'account'` in your `urls.py`.

The `PasswordChangeView` does not expect a namespace when looking up the `password_change_done` view. However, you can override that in your `urls.py` by specifying an explicit `success_url` attribute:

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
​
# change password urls
path('password-change/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(success_url=reverse_lazy('account:password_change_done')), name='password_change'),
```

More info on namespaces: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs

Comment: If I try your proposed solution I'm having this error:
path('password-change/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(success_url=reverse_lazy('account:password_change_done')), name='password_change'),

NameError: name 'reverse_lazy' is not defined

Comment: Everything working after importing the reverse_lazy module and writing your solution.  Thanks a lot, Will!

Answer (score 2):

It works for me:

```
# account urls.py

from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views    
from . import views
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

app_name = 'account'

urlpatterns = [    
    #Password Changes URLs
    path('password_change/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(
        success_url=reverse_lazy('account:password_change_done')
    ), name='password_change'),
    path('password_change/done/',auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(), name='password_change_done'),
]
```

The main link is here:
https://django.fun/en/qa/11928/