# Error 'Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found.' In Django

Tags: python, django

So, I was trying to build a blog website in which the user can reset his password by sending an email to his email address, I was mostly using Django Build In functionality for that. I was trying to make the confirm URL path in which the user can reset his password but was getting an error even when I included the path for password reset confirm.

Error: Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

My urls.py for password-reset

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_view
from django.urls import path

app_name = "blog"

urlpatterns = [
    # for /blog/password-reset/
    path('password-reset/', auth_view.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='blog/password_reset.html'), name="password_reset"),
    # for /blog/password-reset/done/
    path('password-reset/done/', auth_view.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='blog/password_reset_done.html'), name="password_reset_done"),
    # for /blog/password-reset/confirm/<uidb64>/token>
    path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>', auth_view.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='blog/password_reset_confirm.html'), name="password_reset_confirm"),
]
```

Note: I'm not including all the urls cause it's kinda big

My password-reset.html

```
{% extends 'blog/base_for_log.html' %}
{% load  crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block title %}Blog{% endblock %}
    {% block body %}
    <div class = "container">
        <div class="content-section py-5">
            <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">
                        Password Reset
                    </legend>
                    {{ form|crispy }}
                </fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type = "submit">Request Reset Password</button>
            </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>   
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

My blog/password_reset_confirm.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block body %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Reset Password</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Reset Password</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock body %}
```

I expect the output to be a ConnectionResufedError which but I'm getting a NoReverseMatch Error.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: When you got that error? and could you please share your email template. I guess that you want to attach the confirm url inside the email template and the url block should look like this: `<a href="{% url 'blog:password_reset_confirm' %}">Confirm</a>`

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: Actually I think something's wrong with the path in urls.py before it was giving that it couldn't find URL for password_reset_confirm but now that I've added the <a href > tag it gives me error which says that 'Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog\\/password\\-reset\\-confirm\\/(?P<uidb64>[^/]+)\\/(?P<token>[^/]+)$']'

Comment: Yeah, I miss the params. But the point is we need `app_name:url_name` to make it works.

Comment: actually, I didn't needed to define the url as it submits a post request and Django automatically redirects to the password_reset_done page.

Comment: do you have an email template for this? I just worry that if you don't, maybe Django use a template from another app which create a link to `blog:password_reset_confirm` page and that make you in trouble. With me, I have to create an email template inside templates folder and create a link like this: `<a href="{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'app_name:password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}" target="_blank">Click here to confirm</a>`. I don't know what's your email template look like. You can put it into your question so that it could be easier to take a look.

Comment: Actually i did had a email_template for that, I later realized that I gotta do the things "The Django Way" I was having all of my urls in the app/urls.py file and not in the project/urls.py file, django searched for the urls in project/urls.py file not the app/urls.py

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>', ...)` expects two url path parameters (uidb64 and token).

In your template you only have  `href="{% url 'blog:password_reset_confirm' %}"` no parameters are provided, hence function can't reslove to valid url. You need to provide the values like this:

```
href="{% url 'blog:password_reset_confirm' uidb64='uidb64' token='token' %}"
```

Comment: Well Thanks but I actually don't wanna do that, I had the button type == "submit", so it automatically submits the request and should redirect to the password_reset_done page but it just gives me a NoReverse Error, well, I'm still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will solve it, see also [this topic on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49683018/django-2-0-reverse-for-password-change-done-not-found-password-change-done):

I am overriding two paths in my urlpatterns:

```
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
path('password-reset/',
     auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(success_url = reverse_lazy(f'{app_name}:password_reset_done')), 
     name = 'password_reset'),
path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>',
     auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(success_url = reverse_lazy(f'{app_name}:password_reset_complete')), 
     name = 'password_reset_confirm'),
```

As the name of the attribute success_url implies, the success URL will not get resolved with the default paths included in the first line of the above code due to namespace problems, see stackoverflow link above.

Of course, you can keep your template attributes.

{app_name} would be in your case 'blog'
(from .apps import <class derived from django.apps.AppConfig>.name).

Comment: There might be a typo in my answer. The path entry for the PasswordResetConfirmView should end with a slash I think: 'password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/'